# SOLR Upgrade from version 5.4.1 to 8.11.2

Tags: solr, upgrade, solr5, solr8

I am trying to upgrade the Solr version from **5.4.1 to 8.11.2**.
I had installed solr 5.4.1 on my production server which consists of a lot of data which takes a lot of time to reindex data for solr 8.11.2.
I have tried the **IndexUpgrader tool** but it's not working because I am upgrading Solr between two major versions(not consecutive).
Is there any faster way to upgrade the solr version from 5.4.1 to 8.11.2 without affecting my production?

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the different indexupgraders to go through each version. There's a helpful script located at https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex that Jan made that tries to do this automagically for you.

Comment: In Jan script he mentioned that we can upgrade index up to 6.x version and that indexes used by solr 6.x and solr 7.x but I have to upgrade my solr to 8.x version so is it working for 8.x version?

Comment: You'll run the index upgrader from 5 to 6, from 6 to 7 and then from 7 to 8. You might have to update the script to support 7 as well, but the process should be similar to what you can find there.

Comment: Yes I have run index upgrader from 5 to 6,from 6 to 7. But when I had run index upgrade from 7 to 8 it gives error that The index was initially created with 6.x version.

Comment: Hi All! Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but at some time you're probably going to have to bite the reindexing bullet - you might already have been able to reindex in the same since you asked this question. I'm not sure about any magical ways to work around that issue, except for doing the upgrades - and if that fails, I'd probably get ready for reindexing.